# Any way to rename explorer.exe and use it under the new name

Tags: c#, windows, explorer

I am doing an application to being set in place of explorer.exe; and then depending on arguments I receive I want to call the original explorer.exe or not. The reason is being a shell replacement and have the control if an app calls explorer.exe directly.

For that, I had named my application as "explorer.exe" and set under C:\Windows and then the original one was renamed as "explorer2.exe".

The problem is explorer2.exe does not run having this name, it does nothing, just closes. Giving back the original name it starts working.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: [X Y Problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: That's not the way to replace Explorer.  As it is a system component, any changes to how/where it is will probably be blocked by Windows.  I'm pretty sure there is an official way to replace explorer, but can't find it just yet.

Comment: explorer.exe is a System file and is not to be repalced. Attempts to do so will get you detect as a virus ASAP. If the rights and it being in use 99% of the time even allow that. I support the notion taht this is a XY problem

Comment: [How do I replace the system shell (explorer.exe) with another process in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1016380/how-do-i-replace-the-system-shell-explorer-exe-with-another-process-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Setting my app as shell at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell

Causes that while opening explorer.exe it acts as file explorer and not replacing my custom shell. Then that's enough for me.

Thanks Robert Harvey, I missed that point.